# Styles not working

Tags: html, css

I have the following code.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
        .fb{
            position: relative;
            right:-1000px;
         }
         .info{
        position:relative;
         }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="info"> 
    <a href="../jsp/aboutus.jsp" class="anatips" title="About Us">About Us</a> |    
    <a href="../jsp/privacy.jsp" class="anatips" title="Privacy Policy">Privacy Policy</a> 

    <a id = "fb" href="https://www.facebook.com/xyz" target="https://www.facebook.com/xyz"> <img  src="../images/facebook.png" height = 16, width = 16 /> </a>

   </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I want to move the fb link to the right corner. I guess my styling is not working. Or am I going wrong somewhere?

Comment: make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: You should use hash `#` to point to an element by its `id` attribute. periods `.` are used for `.class` selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined a class in your stylesheet

```
.fb{
    position: relative;
    right:-1000px;
}
.info{
    position:relative;
}
```

so while using it you should do

```
<div class="info">
    ...
</div>
<div class="fb">
    ...
</div>
```

OR if you want to use id then

```
#fb{
    position: relative;
    right:-1000px;
}
#info{
    position:relative;
}


<div id="info">
    ...
</div>
<div id="fb">
    ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this `#fb{
 float:right;
         }`

Answer (score 0):

first don't use spaces in attr="smth". Also you use id not class so css selector should be #fb , not .fb

Answer (score 0):

You are using class (`.class`) selectors instead of id (`#id`) selectors in your css

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="info"> 
<a href="../jsp/aboutus.jsp" class="anatips" title="About Us">About Us</a> |    
<a href="../jsp/privacy.jsp" class="anatips" title="Privacy Policy">Privacy Policy</a> 
<a id ="fb" href="https://www.facebook.com/xyz" target="https://www.facebook.com/xyz">     
<img  src="../images/facebook.png" height = 16, width = 16 alt="FB"/> </a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#fb
{
    float:right;
}
.info
{
     position:relative;
}
```

There were no class named fb. **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ywyhj/)**

Answer (score 0):

The styles are not reflecting because you are using `.` instead of `#`. `.` is used while dealing with class, for id use `#`.

Try this:

```
#fb{
  position: fixed;
  right:10px;
         }
 #info{
   position:relative;
}
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fCpss/1/)